# Undefined variable in Laravel Blade view

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a blade view so that I can see the comments from a particular post in my app, but I am getting an undefined variable error:

> ErrorException in a11883d0293a033eba2997ec69df8cdf4ea6a835.php line 9:
>   Undefined variable: comment (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\directory\resources\views\admin\comments\show.blade.php)

I am new to learning Laravel and apologize if this has been answered before but I have been unable to resolve the issue through research on this site thus far. Thank you!

**show.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')
    @if($comment)
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Body</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{$comment->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$comment->author}}</td>
                <td>{{$comment->email}}</td>
                <td>{{$comment->body}}</td>
                <td><a href="{{route('home.post', $comment->post->id)}}">View Post</a></td>
                <td>
                    @if($comment->is_active === 1)
                        {!! Form::open(['method'=>'PATCH','action'=> ['PostCommentsController@update', $comment->id]]) !!}
                        <input type="hidden" name="is_active" value="0">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::submit('Un-approve', ['class'=>'btn btn-info']) !!}
                        </div>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    @else
                        {!! Form::open(['method'=>'PATCH','action'=> ['PostCommentsController@update', $comment->id]]) !!}
                        <input type="hidden" name="is_active" value="1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::submit('Approve', ['class'=>'btn btn-success']) !!}
                        </div>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    @endif
                </td>
                <td>
                    {!! Form::open(['method'=>'DELETE','action'=> ['PostCommentsController@destroy', $comment->id]]) !!}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    @else
        <h1 class="text-center">No Comments</h1>
    @endif
@endsection
```

**PostCommentsController.php**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Comment;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class PostCommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $comments = Comment::all();

        return view('admin.comments.index', compact('comments'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $data = [
            'post_id' => $request->post_id,
            'author' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'photo' => $user->photo->file,
            'body' => $request->body
        ];

        Comment::create($data);

        $request->session()->flash('comment_message', 'Your message has been submitted and is waiting moderation');

        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

        $comments = $post->comments;

        return view('admin.comments.show', compact('comments'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        Comment::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all());

        return redirect('/admin/comments');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Comment::findOrFail($id)->delete();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

**Comment.php Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'post_id',
        'author',
        'email',
        'body',
        'is_active'
    ];

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CommentReply');
    }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `$comments` (plural form) in controller and `$comment` (singular form) in Blade file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is iterating over the `$comments` that you have passed to the view.

So try replacing your `<tbody>` content with the following:

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
<tr>
    <td>{{$comment->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$comment->author}}</td>
    <td>{{$comment->email}}</td>
    <td>{{$comment->body}}</td>
    <td><a href="{{route('home.post', $comment->post->id)}}">View Post</a></td>
    <td>
        @if($comment->is_active == 1)
        {!! Form::open(['method'=>'PATCH','action'=> ['PostCommentsController@update', $comment->id]]) !!}
        <input type="hidden" name="is_active" value="0">
        <div class="form-group">
           {!! Form::submit('Un-approve', ['class'=>'btn btn-info']) !!}
        </div>

        {!! Form::close() !!}

        @else

      {!! Form::open(['method'=>'PATCH','action'=> ['PostCommentsController@update', $comment->id]]) !!}

     <input type="hidden" name="is_active" value="1">
     <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::submit('Approve', ['class'=>'btn btn-success']) !!}
     </div>

     {!! Form::close() !!}
    @endif
   </td>
    <td>
  {!! Form::open(['method'=>'DELETE','action'=> ['PostCommentsController@destroy', $comment->id]]) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) !!}
    </div>
          {!! Form::close() !!}
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

And at the top, replace the `@if` with

```
@if($comments->count())
```

Comment: I am still getting the error, after replacing my body with this!

Comment: Check my edit. And make sure you don't use `$comment` out of the foreach loop.

Comment: Thank you! It resolves the error, but I am getting "No comments" displayed when there are comments for that post that should be showing. I will have to look into this further :)

Comment: Np. You should check your database if you have any comments in there. Also please consider accepting the answer if it helped.